# Random Sampling and PCA

Tags: pca

I am just learning PCA and wondering if it is just a more sophisticated form of sampling. In other words if I have a large data set and take a random sample, would I then apply PCA to it? Or just apply PCA to the data set?

Comment: Since Principal Components Analysis and sampling have almost nothing to do with each other--one analyzes data and the other determines what data to collect--I am wondering whether you mean something else by "PCA". "Point of Closest Approach"? "Prompt Corrective Action"? "Physical Configuration Audit"? "Permanent Corrective Action"? "Power Control Algorithm"? "Process Control & Automation"? "Parallel Cellular Automata"? "Product Complaint Analysis"? "Probable Course of Action"? "Poodle Club of America"?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you were interested in cross validation (i.e. how much your model will predict on a different sample), then you could use PCA on a random subset and then fit that model to the rest of your data.

That being said, PCA is a tool for summarising a covariance matrix in a smaller matrix, so it may not be the best thing to use. Factor Analysis is a better approach if you want to figure out what is happening i

Answer (score 2):

Principal Components Analysis is a way of distilling a large set of variables into a few topics or themes or fundamentals.  It's dimension reduction.  The only resemblance I see to sampling is that sampling also involves a kind of reduction.